# Create a new mailbox for iCloud account via apple script

Tags: icloud, applescript, mail.app

I found script parts to create a mailbox in apple mail via apple script on a MacBook on Monterey:

```
tell application "Mail"
 activate
   make new mailbox with properties {name:"Parent Mailbox1/Child Mailbox1/"}
   make new mailbox with properties {name:"Parent Mailbox2/Child Mailbox2/"}
end tell
```

While execution I get a --> missing value output but the mailbox structure is created locally:

Parent Mailbox1/Child Mailbox1

Parent Mailbox2/Child Mailbox2

If I now want to do this with an iCloud account directly:

```
tell application "Mail"
 activate
 tell account "iCloud"﻿
   make new mailbox with properties {name:"Parent Mailbox1/Child Mailbox1/"}
   make new mailbox with properties {name:"Parent Mailbox2/Child Mailbox2/"}
 end tell
end tell
```

Apple Mail seems to be busy quite a moment by typical busy cursor indication, the value missing output is the same but no mailbox is created in the account. I even tried to enumerate the account id and used it instead and tried at the end of mailbox, but after the busy time around 6-8 seconds per mailbox, no mailbox is created.

I have no clue where to find some debuging information on why mails seems busy but does not create the mailboxes. I thought about extending it with a try catch and error output, but maybe somebody already knows the reason for apple mail behaviour in this area?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I got a hint to remove the last "/" in another forum. Works as desired then. It is unfortunate, that local and iCloud behave differently. I had added it, because I read about some trouble when not adding a "/" at the end but when testing Murphy's Law hit, I did not check that little detail.